# didSelectItemAtIndexPath pushViewController

Tags: ios, model, nsmutablearray, uicollectionview

I'm trying to accomplish something incredibly simple. I am trying to programmatically push to a viewController when the only item in my collection view is pushed. Nothing happens. I believe there is more than one problem in my tangled mess. My understanding of the basics of arrays is clearly anything but. If I put an NSLog line inside my if statement below, I get nothing when pushing my lone item. Here is my didSelectItemAtIndexPath method:

```
NSMutableArray *itemApp = [model.viewControllers objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

if (itemApp == 0) {
    NSLog (@"This does not appear")
    TableViewController *ctc = [[TableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:ctc animated:YES];
}
```

model is defined in viewDidLoad:

```
    model = [[SimpleModel alloc] init];
```

SimpleModel is mentioned in the .m  implementation:

```
@implementation smileController;

{
SimpleModel *model;
}
```

viewControllers is property of the SimpleModel class, along with its friend, apps:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *apps;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *viewControllers;
```

Here is the SimpleModel.m

```
 - (id)init
{
if (self = [super init])
{

    self.apps = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"1", nil];

    self.viewControllers = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:self.apps.count];

    TableViewController *tvc = [[TableViewController alloc] init];

    [self.viewControllers addObject:tvc];
}
return self;
}
```

Comment: Why would you expect itemApp to equal 0? It should be tvc, shouldn't it?

Comment: Having `if (itemApp == 0)` is the same as `if (itemApp == nil)`. Since your `model.viewControllers` array can't have any `nil` values, the `itemApp` variable can only be `nil` if `self.viewController` is also `nil`. Given the name `self.viewControllers`, wouldn't getting a specific value return a `UIViewController` object and not another `NSMutableArray`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `SimpleModel.m` you populate the `viewControllers` array with a single `TableViewController`.

Given this, when the first block of code you posted should be more like this:

```
TableViewController *itemApp = [model.viewControllers objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

if (itemApp) {
    NSLog (@"This should appear")
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:itemApp animated:YES];
}
```

This assumes you want to push the view controller you obtain from the `model.viewControllers` property.

Please note that `itemApp` can only be `nil` if `model` or `model.viewControllers` are `nil`.